# how to display values in jsp through java class

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a database with tables and values. I want to fetch that data and display it in jsp page. Don't want to write query in jsp page, separate java class,creating java object values and then displaying it in select field in jsp. please help me...

here is my java class 
                p

```
ublic class EmpBean {
                    public java.util.List dataList(){
                        ArrayList list=new ArrayList();
                        try{
                             Class.forName("driver");
                                   Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("url", "user", "pwd");
                                   Statement st=con.createStatement();
                                   System.out.println("hiiiii");
                                   ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from employee");
                                   while(rs.next()){
                                       list.add(rs.getString("name"));
                                       list.add(rs.getString("address"));
                                       list.add(rs.getString("contactNo"));
                                       list.add(rs.getString("email"));


                        }
                                   System.out.println(rs.getString("contactNo"));
                        }
                        catch(Exception e){}
                        return   list;

                        }

                }

//and my jsp file
                <%@page language="java" import="java.util.*" %>
                <html>
                <body> 
                <table border="1" width="303">
                <tr>
                <td width="119"><b>Name</b></td>

                </tr>
                <%Iterator itr;%>
                <%EmpBean p = new EmpBean();
                List list= (List) p.dataList(); %>
                for (itr=list.iterator(); itr.hasNext(); ){
                %>
                <tr>
                <select name="" id="" style="width: 150px;"">
                                <option value="-1"><%=itr.next()%></option>
                </select>

                </tr>
                <%}%>
                </table>
                </body>
                </html>
```

Comment: Have you tried something show us some code ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think you should try this

```
    public class EmpBean {
                public java.util.List dataList(){
                    ArrayList list=new ArrayList();
                    try{
                         Class.forName("driver");
                               Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("url", "user", "pwd");
                               Statement st=con.createStatement();
                               System.out.println("hiiiii");
                               ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from employee");
                               while(rs.next()){
                                   list.add(rs.getString("name"));
                                   list.add(rs.getString("address"));
                                   list.add(rs.getString("contactNo"));
                                   list.add(rs.getString("email"));


                    }
                               System.out.println(rs.getString("contactNo"));
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){}
                    return   list;

                    }

            }
```

Assuming this class working fine and it is returning list with some value

now on your jsp page

```
           <%@page language="java" import="java.util.*" %>
            <html>
            <body> 
            <table border="1" width="303">
            <tr>
            <td width="119"><b>Name</b></td>

            </tr>
            <%
                  ArrayList list;
                  EmpBean emp = new EmpBean();
                  list = emp.dataList();
                  ArrayList li = (ArrayList) li.get(0);

            %>
            <tr>
            <select name="" id="" style="width: 150px;"">
                            <option value="-1"><%=li.get(1)%></option>
            </select>

            </tr>

            </table>
            </body>
            </html>
```

just check this code...it might happen that values fetched may be wrong here just check the values by changing list indexing and also if you can surround the whole scriptlets thing with try catch so that if exception occurs it will be easy to find bug...good luck and don't worry if it doesn't works i will give you sample code for sure i am using this code my project

Comment: thanks for helping me.. is it possible you to send your sample code to my mail id.. varadrv@gmail.com

Comment: surely I will...may be you have to wait till evening

Comment: @varad _ check out your mail.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your String username = String.valueOf(connect.getTasks(mysql)); and you wanted to display username then store it in a page context as pageContext.setAttribute( "username", username )

and then display anywhere or simply use
<%=String.valueOf(connect.getTasks(mysql)>

I am not getting your problem and apologize if i am confusing you
even more...

Roses

Comment: Actuly i want display the database values in jsp by calling java class in jsp and i dnt want write query in jsp..

Answer (score 1):

In Java class you can create the connection and execute the query and store it in the ArrayList. Set the list into the session's setAttribute function. It can be then redirected to the jsp page by using sendRedirect() method.

Before implementing this have a look into the core tags of JSP in this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.html.

But before all these can you paste the bloc of code you are executing.

Comment: i dont want use senRedirect() coz i m working on school project and for tat i need to display academic year,section,medium ... etc in drop down format almost in evry jsp file. if i use sendRedirect then i need to write seprate servlet for evry jsp.. so please help me from last 3 days m working on that only..

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are asking for [***Hibernate***](http://www.hibernate.org/docs).

This creates plain old java objects for your database. It takes some getting used to but it is exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: -1: Suggesting a framework does not solve the question. Still how would you display the objects in the `<select>`?

Comment: You're right, as for displaying the results in a select i'll wait for somebody to ask how thats done before I explain. I am new to posting on stack overflow you'll have to excuse me. I had trouble reading his question. It sounded to me like he didn't want JSP scriptlets at all.

Comment: Hmmm, I can understand ... now @varad just screwed up the formatting I had done in the question. :-)

Comment: lol, yeah I understand i've just rewritten an answer i gave three times... no worries i need the practice... how does a guy go about sending a private message in Stackoverflow anyway....

Comment: @PrakashK i apologize if i am confusing you even more